# Where can I find a high tide for the Atlantic coast of France from 11 July to mid August 1941?

Tags: world-war-two

I am researching an alternate-history novel and have the raid on St. Nazaire happening in 1941. I need a high tide for the night-time raid.  Is there any place I can find tide tables for that time period?

Comment: Possible source: http://refmar.shom.fr/fr/c/document_library/get_file?uuid=1f0dde58-a0f4-4681-b3b5-4c06fb5fd1d4&groupId=10227

Comment: There are several applications that let you calculate the tides for a particular place on a specific date for yourself. An example that I have used in the past is [Tides](http://stormy.ca/tides/index.html)

Comment: Alternately - don't specify the key date. Identify it as H-Hour on D-Day, the standard military terminology of the time, and simply describe the tidal conditions being met. Unless the protaganist is to be very senior (s)he wouldn't be privy to the actual day, for security reasons, until *locked up* on the transport ship the day before.